# Getting the DB2 Resource online in Failover Cluster

Tags: high-availability, failovercluster, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-cluster, db2

I'm using **DB2 10.1 Enterprise Server Edition** on **Windows Server 2012 R2**

After adding the DB2 resource to the cluster using the *db2wolfi* command, I go to the resources tab which is in the cluster properties and I find the new resource added under the user defined section. However, the problem is that the display name shows as **Resource not available**. I need to know *why this happens* and *how to solve this problem* because ahead when this resource is added to the role I created, I cannot make it online.

Comment: I found the solution after long hours of hit and try. In Windows Server 2012 R2, when you create a new role, follow all the steps and when you are asked to choose the resource, don't choose anything and complete the remaining steps. After your role is created, right click it and _add a resource_, choose **Generic Service** and choose your DB2 Server.